# How to retrieve nested model data from another model? : undefined method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, rails-activerecord

So the basis of my code so far is:

a customer `has_one` calendar

a calendar `belongs_to` a customer

a calendar `has_many` events

an event `belongs_to` a calendar

I am trying to, when creating a new event, specify the customer and calendar it belongs to but it throws error "undefined method `Calendar'":

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @event = Event.new
    @currentcalendar = current_customer.calendar # this is where it is failing

  end

  def create
    if @event = @currentcalendar.build.event(event_params)
      redirect_to '/main'
    else
      redirect_to '/compose'
    end
  end

  private

  def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:calendar_id, :name, :starts_at, :ends_at) 
  end
end
```

this is my current_customer method within application_controller:

```
def current_customer
    if (customer_id = session[:customer_id])
      @current_customer ||= Customer.find_by(id: customer_id)
    elsif (customer_id = cookies.signed[:customer_id])
      customer = Customer.find_by(id: customer_id)
      if customer && customer.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
        session[:customer_id] = customer.id #log in
        @current_customer = customer

      end
    end
  end
```

Here are the related controller files. Customer:

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController

  def new

    @customer = Customer.new
    @businesses = Business.all
    @calendar = Calendar.new

  end

  def create

    @customer = Customer.create(customer_params)

    @calendar = @customer.build_calendar
    @customer.save!
    session[:customer_id] = @customer.id

    redirect_to '/'
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => ex
    render action: 'new', alert: ex.message
  end

  private
  def customer_params
    params.require(:customer).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :business_no, :email, :password, :business_id)
  end
```

Calendar:

```
class CalendarsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @calendar = Calendar.new(calendar_params)

  end

  def create
    @calendar = Calendar.new(calendar_params)
  end

private
  def calendar_params
    params.require(:customer_id)
  end

end
```

I'm very new to Ruby/ Rails and so can't figure this out by myself. Is this problem occurring because I have wrongly created my calendar? I wanted it to be created when its user is created, which works, but I just don't know how to get to the calendar and user within the events controller.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: these are the model classes.

customer:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :business
  has_one :calendar

  has_secure_password

  attr_accessor :remember_token

  #remembers a user in the database for  use in persistent sessions
  def remember
    self.remember_token = Customer.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, Customer.digest(remember_token))
  end

  def Customer.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
        BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end

  def forget
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
  end

  def Customer.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  #returns true if the given token matches the digest
  def authenticated?(remember_token)
    BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(remember_token)
  end


end
```

calendar:

```
class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :events


end
```

event:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :calendar

end
```

Comment: Could you post the full error message?

Comment: `but it throws error` - when you get an error in the app and you are asking SO question, you should always include the full error message together with a stacktrace. From what you posted it seems that you missed `new` somewhere and you are calling `Calendar(params)`. To tell where exactly you need to check the very first line of the stacktrace. That is assuming your error is really saying `Calendar`, not `calendar`. I have a feeling it is `calendar` though, and the full message will be `undefined method calendar for NilClass`, is it right?

Comment: Please include your models in the post as well, it’s clear the error came from models.

Comment: I have edited my post now to include the models. the full error message is: 
NoMethodError in EventsController#new 


undefined method `Calendar' for #<Customer:0x63df0b0>

Comment: @mudasobwa ok, for some reason it is no longer throwing this error, however it is still not working I think, because when i highlight 'calendar' in current_customer.calendar  it just refers to &calendar on the same line. Am I getting the wrong end of the stick here? would this really be all the code I need to retrieve a specific customer's calendar?

Comment: @BroiSatse - if I change my code to 'at'calendar = 'at'customer.calendar this error occurs. Am I supposed to be using 'at'customer or current_customer?

Comment: Your `current_customer` returns `nil` if there is no logged in user found. Calling `calendar` on `nil` produces the error you see. Make sure you call this method if and only the `current_customer` returns not nil value.

Comment: @mudasobwa ok that makes sense. Now when I activate the create method for events, it throws the error: 
NoMethodError in EventsController#create 


undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass. This happens on the line @event = @calendar.build.event(event_params)

Answer (score 0):

Your `current_customer` can be `nil` at times. To avoid this you can add a `before_filter` callback that checks if there is a customer that is logged in or not.

In your `application_controller` create a method called `customer_found?`

```
def customer_found?
  current_customer.present?
end
```

Change your events controller to

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :customer_found?
  before_filter :prepare_calendar, only: [:new, :create]

  def new
    @event = Event.new    
  end

  def create
    if @event = @current_calendar.build.event(event_params)
      redirect_to '/main'
    else
      redirect_to '/compose'
    end
  end

  private

  def prepare_calendar
    @current_calendar = current_customer.calendar
  end

  def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:calendar_id, :name, :starts_at, :ends_at) 
  end
end
```

Since you did not assign your `@current_calendar` in your create method then you are gonna get `undefined method build for nil class`. You need to initialize the variable since it can not get it from the `new` method. Each action has its own independent variables so make sure to prepare all necessary variables before using them.